# how to disable YellowBox in react-native totally in a native way ? not in JavaScript

Tags: react-native

I know console.disableYellowBox = true could be answer. But I want ban it with all my control because my App has multiple package and I do not want to use console.disableYellowBox = true in every package.

is there any way to achieve this by set a config in shaking bar ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the new React version replacing the import to:

import { LogBox } from "react-native";

and adding this line inside App.js

LogBox.ignoreAllLogs();

And it's working good for me.

Comment: yeah you can do that, but your just covering the problem not solving it (which is not recommended)

Answer (score -1):

You have multiple way's in doing that, which is not recommended since you want to know what's causing these warnings and sometimes it's important informations you need to know, here is some of the ways you can do

> Warnings will be displayed on screen with a yellow background. These
> alerts are known as YellowBoxes. Click on the alerts to show more
> information or to dismiss them.
>
> As with a RedBox, you can use **console.warn()** to trigger a YellowBox.
>
> YellowBoxes can be disabled during development by using
> `console.disableYellowBox = true;`

1. using ignore

`console.ignoredYellowBox = ['Warning: Each', 'Warning: Failed'];`

`ignoredYellowBox` allows you to ignore certain warnings as you can see in the example above.

2. using disableYellowBox

   `console.disableYellowBox = true;`

`disableYellowBox` allows you to disable it completely from your app.

however both these ways you need to use inside App.js before you render you app.

**example:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
 
//console.disableYellowBox = true;
//OR
//console.ignoredYellowBox = ['Warning: Each', 'Warning: Failed'];

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {/*Your Code will be here*/}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Take a look at [Debugging React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging) to learn more about **YellowBox**

```
// RN >= 0.52
import {YellowBox} from 'react-native';
YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Warning: ReactNative.createElement']);

// RN < 0.52
console.ignoredYellowBox = ['Warning: ReactNative.createElement'];
```